# Cart data is available at navbar component but not in Cart component (reactJs commerceJs)

Tags: reactjs, components, cart, react-props, commerce

this is the code I am working with. When the cart component is not active the cart data loads perfectly, but when the cart component is active cart data is undefined.

```
import './App.css';
    import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';
    import { NavBar, Products, Cart } from './components';
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    function App() {
      const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
      const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
      const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const { data} = await commerce.products.list();
        setProducts(data);
      }
      const fetchCart = async () => {
        setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
      }
      const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
        const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);
        setCart(item);
        fetchCart();
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
        fetchCart();
      }, [])
      return (
        <div>
          <NavBar totalItems={cart.total_items}></NavBar>
          <Products products={products} handleAddToCart={ handleAddToCart}/>
          <Cart cart={cart}></Cart>
          
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

NavBar component is receiving the prop. But whenever I pass the cart data into the cart component, data is not being received by Cart component. Even in App.js, the data shows undefined.
[When Cart component is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGdtG.png)

[When cart component is not active the top right corner shows cart data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJcbE.png)

**Cart Component**

```
import React from 'react';
    import { Container, Typography, Button, Grid } from '@material- 
     ui/core';
    import useStyles from './styles';
    
    
    const Cart = ({ cart}) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      // alert(cart);
      const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
      const EmptyCart = () => {
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">You have no items in your shopping 
         cart. Start adding some!</Typography>
      }
      const FilledCart = () => {
        <>
          <Grid container spacing={ 3}>
            {cart.line_items.map((item) => (
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id}>
                <div>{ item.name}</div>
              </Grid>
              
            ))}
          </Grid>
          <div className={classes.cardDetails}>
            <Typography variant="h4">Subtotal: 
             {cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol}</Typography>
            <div>
              <Button className={ classes.emptyButton} size="large" 
               type="button" variant="contained" color="secondary">Empty 
               Cart</Button>
              <Button className={ classes.checkoutButton} size="large" 
               type="button" variant="contained" 
               color="primary">Checkout</Button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </>
      }
      return (
        <Container>
          <div className={ classes.toolbar}>
            <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3"> Your 
             Shopping 
             Cart</Typography>
            { isEmpty? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}
          </div>
        </Container>
      );
    };
    
    export default Cart;
```

**Navbar Component**

```
import React from 'react';
    import { AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton, Badge, MenuItem, Menu, 
    Typography } 
    from '@material-ui/core';
    import { ShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';
    import useStyles from './styles';
    import image from '../../images/commerce.png'
    
    const NavBar = ({ totalItems}) => {
        const classes = useStyles();
        return (
            <>
                <AppBar position="fixed" className={ classes.appBar} 
                 color="inherit">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={ 
                         classes.title} 
                         color="inherit">
                            <img src={image} alt="My Shop" className= 
                             {classes.image} height="25px" />
                            My Shop
                        </Typography>
                        <div className={classes.grow}></div>
                        <div className={classes.button}>
                            <IconButton aria-label="Show Cart Button" 
                             color="inherit">
                                <Badge badgeContent={totalItems} 
                                 color="secondary">
                                    <ShoppingCart></ShoppingCart>
                                </Badge>
                            </IconButton>
                        </div>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </>
        );
    };
        
      export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Please try to include all relevant code. Update your question to include the `Cart` component. Can you also clarify how `NavBar` has correct cart data but the component holding that state doesn't?

Comment: Hello there,
I have attached screenshots and codes also. Can you please help?

Comment: Error is saying that `cart.line_items` is undefined. This seems to be set by `commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity)`, though, so you should check what this function returns. Can you update your question to include this `commerce` code and drop a `console.log` or `debugger` on the line after `const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);` in `handleAddToCart` to see what the value of `item` is that you are updating `cart` state to?

Comment: When the Cart component in App.js is inactive the console.log(cart) shows cart data. but when I active the Cart component in app.js the console.log is undefined. 
if I pass cart.total_items in NavBar component, it shows cart items count in NavBar as the pictures described. But when the Cart component is active the cart.total_items has no value. This is like ghost playing to me.